# Concatenar filas CONCAT_WS con la funcion REVERSE con mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, concat

les explico mi problema:

Estoy usando mysql workbench, necesito concatenar NOMBRE, APELLIDO1 y APELLIDO2 junto con la función REVERSE, para que se vea en orden invertido. No logro conseguir que funcione. A continuación dejo mi código:

***SELECT concat_ws(' ',nombre,apellido1,apellido2) as 'Nombre Completo', reverse(concat_ws(' ',nombre,apellido1,apellido2)) as 'Invertido' FROM alumno;***

Comment: En este caso, la herramienta que utilizas es irrelevante en tu pregunta, ya que tu sistema gestor de base de datos es **mysql**. Por favor, haz clic en [edit] y elimina las secciones que mencionan a workbench, y también dale formato a tu código, para una mejor lectura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que se muestren los campos invertidos y ademas todas las letras invertidas puedes hacer ésta consulta:

```
SELECT REVERSE(CONCAT(nombre, apellido1, apellido2)) FROM plate;
```

Y si lo que quieres es que se muestren los campos invertidos pero los nombres sean legibles puedes usar ésta otra consulta:

```
SELECT CONCAT(apellido2, apellido1, nombre) FROM plate;
```